# Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, relational-database

i want to display the id of the user who posted on the wall but it says the error.I am learning relationships in laravel.
Post belongs to 1 user.
1 user can have many posts.
Thanks.

Post model

```
class Post extends Model
{
        public function users(){
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\User');
}
```

post Controller

```
class PostsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $p = \App\Post::all();
        return view('posts.index',compact('p'));
    }
}
```

posts\index

```
<?php 
    foreach ($p as  $value) {
    echo $value->title." ".$value->body." posted by ".$value->users->id." 
    <br>";}
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: your post only has 1 user as writer(author) so make it `user()` instead of `users()`

2. Add relationship to user model `public function posts() {` relationship is `hasMany`
3. Get your data with eagle load `$posts = Post::with('user')->get();`

In that way you can have your author info in blade like:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
{{$post->title}} <br>
{{$post->user->name}}
@endforeach
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: just by making method users() to user() , problem is solved (y) , but i am not able to understand the logic behind it , i mean function name could be any

Comment: Function name goes by relationship, if you get array of data you&#39;ll use plural if you get object you&#39;ll use singular. E.g. user has many post so function is posts (hasMany), post has one user then function is user (belongsTo).

Answer (score 0):

You can dd($value->users) and watching it!

Answer (score -1):

```
$value->users->id
```

Should be either

A: `$value->users()->id`

or update your controller like so:

B: `$p = \App\Post::with('users')->get();`

Comment: A give error
B does'nt works , gives the same exception

Comment: Are you sure the post(s) you are trying to display actually has a linked user in your database?

Comment: Can you confirm that your `posts` table has a `user_id` field?

Comment: Can you try using `php artisan tinker` to test without your view? something like: `php artisan tinker`; `$post = \App\Post::first()`; `$post->users->id`;

Comment: Can you copy/paste what `$post` and `$post->users` return?

Comment: id: 1,
     title: "Elections",
     body: "this is my 1st post ,so plz like it.",
     user_id: 2,
     created_at: "2018-08-16 00:00:00",
     updated_at: "2018-08-02 00:00:00",

post->users->id returns PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'id' of non-object in Psy Shell code on line 1

Comment: $post->users it returns null

Comment: If you get `null` on `$post->users`, that means that Eloquent isn't able to find a user with an ID of 2. I am very sure that the `users` method on your Post class is correct and should link to `user` properly (other than a missing closing `}`). I'd be curious to see a dump of that database.

Comment: Forget to put `{` in Post model for `users()`

Comment: Some feedback on the downvote would be appreciated; this is a pretty simple solution. Should I have elaborated more?